# Get a value included from a lookup column using the JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Related:
[How to retrieve a ListItem using the Javascript Client Object Model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/how-to-retrieve-a-listitem-using-the-javascript-client-object-model)

In my previous question I was able to successfully retrieve a basic value from a list item.  My problem is that I am now trying to retrieve a value from a LookUp column `get_item` no longer seems to work.

When I do an alert, I get `[object Object]` instead of the value that is in there.

Code I am using:

```
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        alert(oDeptItem.get_item('Department'));
        $('#contact').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department'));
    }
```

Should I be using something besides `get_item` to values from LookUp columns?

Comment: `get_lookupValue()` will also work with fields of Type "User"

Comment: What about columns that belongs to the lookup field? For example Department name, Department No and so on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add the `get_lookupValue()` function after my `get_item` call:

```
alert(oDeptItem.get_item('Department').get_lookupValue());
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

For those not using JSOM and need a solution using REST + JSON, this can be done using the REST API and OData. For example if the list in questions is Employee with a Department Lookup field. We can send a REST request with this format:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employee')/items?$select=Department/Name,DepartmentId,Name,Id&$expand=Department
```

Note the OData request parameters $select and $expand (this is needed to get other fields from the lookup list). This request should return:

Employee id and name
Department id and name

More information can be found here:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using Abe Misseler answer:

```
var oItem ='';
function retrieveWebSite() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);

        var lstObject = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
        oItem = lstObject.getItemById(5);
        clientContext.load(oItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)       
        );
    });
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var look  = oItem.get_item('LookupColumnName').get_lookupValue();
    var title = oItem.get_item('Title');
    var id = oItem.get_id();
    alert("Loook up column value: "+look);
    alert("Title column: "+title);
    alert("Id column value: "+id);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```