# How to get a full name from a User Lookup Field using ECMA CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

How do you get a user's full name using the ECMAScript (JavaScript) CSOM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a value included from a lookup column using the javascript Client Object Model?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/how-to-get-a-value-included-from-a-lookup-column-using-the-javascript-client-obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See dupe question - [Get a value included from a lookup column using the JavaScript Client Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/how-to-get-a-value-included-from-a-lookup-column-using-the-javascript-client-obj)

```
FIELD.get_lookupValue()
```