# Error using javascript to retrieve a SharePoint list's items

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, caml, query

I am trying to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method to query items of a column of a list in my SP site via javascript (the reason I am doing this is to display that info on the page by modifying the html tags in the DOM), but I am only able to query the "ID" column of my list, which is a Picture Library. The column I want is actually a Text column titled "Link to Page", but it is throwing the following error

```
"The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."
```

Here are the relevant sections of code that I am using:

```
function retrieveListItems() {

var newLinks = [];

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Link to Page\'/></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

    return newLinks;
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();


    var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();

    var newLinks = new Array(parseInt(itemCount) - 1);

    alert("array length: " +  newLinks.length);

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        newLinks[i] = oListItem.get_item('Link to Page');
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

$(document).ready(function() {ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems,"sp.js");});
```

I thought my problem might be similar to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/how-to-retrieve-a-listitem-using-the-javascript-client-object-model) but that solution doesn't seem to be working for me. I'd be grateful for any pointers on this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Internal Name of the column, so its probably:

```
Link_x0020_to_x0020_Page
```

Easy way to check the internal name is from the url when you edit the column, and check the "Field=" part of the URL:

```
FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B6045095F%2DC5AF%2D47D5%2DA481%2D27665B46E343%7D&Field=Link%5Fx0020%5Fto%5Fx0020%5FPage
```

Replace %5F with underscore, or just paste the url into a [url decoder tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: I was going to mention in my question that I had a suspicion that it might be the whitespace causing the problem. I will try this out and get back, thanks.